# Bubble sort of array implementation gives truth value as ambiguous

Tags: python, arrays

Below is my bubble sort algorithm. When I load a numpy file for a 2D Image, i want to sort the x-coordinates only.

```
img = np.load('2Dimage.npy') #Loads 2D Image 
x = (img[:,0,np.newaxis].T - img[:,0,np.newaxis])**2 #x-coordinates of the image (3584, 3584) array.


def bubbleSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j]  > arr[j + 1]  :
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    return(arr)
    
bubbleSort(x)
```

When the array is something simple like `x = [1,3,5,9]` it works! But for a higher dimensional array which I use, I get an error to say  `if arr[j]  > arr[j + 1]  : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. So I change the line to `if (arr[j] - arr[j + 1]).any() > 0 :` But again get another error which I am not sure how to fix?

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'any'`

Comment: It said `Use a.any()`, not `Use a.any`.

Comment: Well let's suppose `arr[j]` is `[1, 2, 3]` and `arr[j + 1]` is `[-2, 10, 3]`. What is `arr[j]  > arr[j + 1]` supposed to check/do in the context of sorting?

Comment: Now you've changed the error message you supposedly get, but you must have changed something else in your code, too, otherwise you would have gotten the current error message earlier as well. If `arr[j] - arr[j + 1]` is an `int`, you can't get the original error message.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to sort the x-coordinates only.

You have correct implementation of bubbleSort. But since your data is 2D (rows X columns) and since you want to sort only along x-axis (i.e rows), you have to call your bubleSort for each row.

```
x = np.random.randint(0,256, (8, 8))


def bubbleSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j]  > arr[j + 1]  :
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    return(arr)

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
  x[i] = bubbleSort(x[i])

print (x)
```

Output:

```
array([[  4,  53,  82, 141, 207, 232, 238, 246],
       [120, 154, 174, 195, 209, 230, 234, 243],
       [ 18,  25,  47,  55, 112, 145, 216, 249],
       [  3,  64,  75,  81, 146, 186, 208, 237],
       [ 29,  30,  44,  81, 114, 219, 244, 247],
       [  6,  10,  50,  73, 108, 155, 177, 193],
       [ 20,  20,  33,  73,  75, 102, 131, 195],
       [ 34,  52,  75, 101, 105, 169, 218, 242]])
```